# The numbers in these patterns go together following the same rule. Find the missing number.

Tags: pattern-recognition

I don't see the pattern of the numbers, can someone tell me what the pattern is?[image]

Comment: The second number in each pair is probably intended to be the smallest prime greater than the first number. These questions asking you to find patterns are very badly defined from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: It is satisfied except for 37, cos 31 is the smallest prime greater than 30.

Comment: I said "probably intended". I have no faith in the people who set these dumb questions actually getting the details right. Will you be able to find out what the "correct" answer is and why?

Comment: Thank you, I know it is so dumb, I can't find the so called "correct" answer, but probably someone else can?

Comment: I meant, will the solution to the question with justification be published?

Answer (score 0):

Second number is the first prime greater than the first number, so $41$.

---

Or any of the other options by a suitable convoluted argument

Comment: I tried this but this is false since first prime after 30 is 31 .

Comment: Thanks! But I think @BirdSetFree7 is right, 37 is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second number is the smallest Primes after the first number in pair with an extra condition that it has to at least 40 + 6 ( significance of 6 is the AP starting from 0 in pair (0,2) ) . Eg- $29\geq 25+4$